# Symfony FOS UserBundle Remove fos_user.email.already_used

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony3 and FOSUserBundle and when a user tries to create an account and they have chosen an email which is already registered they get the error "fos_user.email.already_used" ... This looks horrible!!! How can I output a better message such as "Email has already been taken".

Here's part of my security.yml which may help. Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide...

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the locale in your `config.yml` ?http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

Comment: Best way is to overwrite the default security template and use you own translation domain, this will give you full control over the error messages.